# How to start a server before protractor runs and clean up afterwards

Tags: javascript, protractor, webpack-dev-server

It seems protractor doesn't provide any out of the box solution for starting a server before it runs.   Having to run multiple commands before functional tests will run is a bad user experience and bad for automated testing.

Angular-cli has its own solution that is rather complicated, which this plugin claims to duplicate, although it doesn't work for me and may be unmaintained.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-webpack

EDIT: BETTER SOLUTION ACCEPTED BELOW

I came up with a solution using child_process.exec that seems to work well, although I don't like it very much.  I'd like to share it in case anyone needs it and to see if anyone can come up with a better solution.

Launch the process in the beforeLaunch hook of protractor:

```
beforeLaunch: () => {
    webpackServerProcess = exec(`webpack-dev-server --port=3003 --open=false`, null, () => { 
      console.log(`Webpack Server process reports that it exited. Its possible a server was already running on port ${port}`)
    });
  },
```

Then above the configuration block we set up the exit handlers to make positively sure that server gets killed when we are done.

```
let webpackServerProcess; // Set below in beforeLaunch hook
function cleanUpServer(eventType) {
  console.log(`Server Cleanup caught ${eventType}, killing server`);
  if (webpackServerProcess) {
    webpackServerProcess.kill();
    console.log(`SERVER KILLED`);
  }
}

[`exit`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `uncaughtException`].forEach((eventType) => {
  process.on(eventType, cleanUpServer.bind(null, eventType));
})
```

The various event listeners are needed to handle cntrl+c events and situations where the process is killed by ID.  Strange that node does not provide an event to encompass all of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much more reliable way to do it using the webpack-dev-server node api.  That way no separate process is spawned and we don't have to clean anything.  Also, it blocks protractor until webpack is ready.

```
  beforeLaunch: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new WebpackDevServer(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')()), {
        // Do stuff
      }).listen(APP_PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
        console.log('webpack dev server error is ', err)
        resolve()
      }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('dev server error ', error)
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  },
```

Comment: This answer does not work as is.  Could you expand it a bit?  "WebpackDevServer" is not defined.  Do you get that from requiring "webpack-dev-server"?  What the "webpack" function you are calling?  What is supposed to go in "do stuff"?

Comment: Could this be used to not start the browser until an API request is complete?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/examples/api/simple/server.js

Answer (score 1):

Protractor also has `onCleanUp` that will run after all the specs in the file have finished.

And you are doing the right thing by keeping a reference to your process so that you can kill it later.

```
let webpackServerProcess;
beforeLaunch: () {
    webpackServerProcess = exec('blah'); // you could use spawn instead of exec
},
onCleanUp: () {
    process.kill(webpackServerProcess.pid);
    // or webpackServerProcess.exit();
}
```

Since you are launching the serverProcess with child_process.exec, and not in a detached state, it should go away if the main process is killed with SIGINT or anything else. So you might not even have to kill it or cleanup.

Comment: Sweet, all good input.  I tried "oncleanup" but it failed a lot of time on interrupts or other situations, so I had to do the manual watching.  Otherwise it would stick around on the system and take up a port.  Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

```
// conf.js

var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
const path = require('path');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpack = require('webpack');
let webpackServerProcess;

beforeLaunch: () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const compiler = webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'));
        const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
          stats: 'errors-only'
        });
        server.listen(0, 'localhost', () => {
          // `server.listeningApp` will be returned by `server.listen()`
          // in `webpack-dev-server@~2.0.0`
          const address = server.listeningApp.address();
          config.baseUrl = `http://localhost:${address.port}`;
          resolve();
        });
      }, 5000);
    });
  };

exports.config = {

  framework: 'jasmine',
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['Test/spec.js'],
  directConnect: true,
   // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
     capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'/*,
        chromeOptions: {
             args: [ '--headless','--log-level=1', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--window-size=1920x1200' ]
           }*/
     },

    onPrepare: function() {

          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
             consolidateAll: true,
             filePrefix: 'guitest-xmloutput',
             savePath: 'reports'
          }));

          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
             savePath: 'reports/',
             screenshotsFolder: 'images',
             takeScreenshots: true,
             takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
             cleanDestination: false,
             fileName: 'TestReport'
          }));
       },
}

onCleanUp: ()=> {
           //process.kill(webpackServerProcess.pid);
            webpackServerProcess.exit();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).